# Setting Google maps circles using Smart Map plugin

Tags: javascript, plugin-smartmap

So, I'm trying to set circles around marker locations using Smart Map and some JS.

I've got the following which gives no errors, but outputs no circles.

```
$(function () {

  $.each( smartMap.marker, function( key, value ) {

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: smartMap.map['smartmap-mapcanvas-1'],
                    radius: 40233,    // 25 miles in metres
                    fillColor: '#000000'
                 });
    circle.bindTo('center', marker, value.getPosition());

    });

  });

});
```

I'm out of ideas at this point!

Comment: I haven't used Circle, but most of what you're doing is outside of Smart Map. You're largely just using the native Google Maps API here.

Comment: Yeah, i think this should work just fine, but isn't, so i was trying to narrow it down in case there was some smart map edge case i didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, so let me know if this does/doesn't work...

Here's how you're starting your loop:

```
$.each( smartMap.marker, function( key, value ) {
```

And near the end, you reference a `marker` object:

```
circle.bindTo('center', marker, value.getPosition());
```

But as far as I can tell, `marker` is never defined. Did you mean to pass in `value` instead?

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't say marker, that should say value, but i was changing some stuff and forgot to change it back before pasting this code. It doesn't work with value there.